# View spec fails with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, kaminari

The code works on localhost but the view spec is failing and I can't figure out why.

In the view I have:

```
<%= paginate events %>
```

In the controller I have:

```
expose(:events) { @events }

def method
  @cat_ids = event_categories.collect(&:id)
  page = params[:page] || 1
  per = params[:per] || 4
  @events = Event.order(:start).where(event_category_id: [@cat_ids])
                 .where('start >= ?', Date.today)
                 .where(workflow_state: 'live')
                 .page(page).per(per)
end
```

In the view spec I have tried all the different methods people suggested on previous similar questions but none have worked. We are using FactoryBot.

Here is some of the things I have tried:

```
  before do
    view_allow some_events
    allow(view).to receive(:page).and_return(1)
    allow(some_events).to receive(:current_page).and_return(1)
    allow(some_events).to receive(:total_pages).and_return(2)
  end
```

Error messages I receive based on what is above are as follows:

```
Failure/Error: <%= paginate events %>

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `total_pages' for #<Event…

ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:controller=>"events", :page=>nil}

undefined method `current_page' for #<Event
```

Let me know if you need to see any more of my code as I am still quite new to this.

Comment: where is `event_categories` defined? 
Are you sure `@events = Event.order(:start).where(event_category_id: [@cat_ids])` returns data?

Comment: @lacostenycoder
Yes it does return data as it works on localhost it just seems to be the view test failing. Its found by the params. [@cat_ids] returns an array of the id's as integers.